# Facebook SDK with Swift 4/Xcode 10: Argument type 'SDKLoggingBehavior?' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm revisiting an old project (built with Swift 3 and now using Swift 4) and it looks like there are some issues with the Facebook SDK.

I googled the initial issues and came upon a solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/267) which advises adding to my pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['FacebookCore', 'FacebookLogin'].include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

[Here is the complete podfile](https://pastebin.com/PzVD4Z0W).

After `pod install` and running the project, it seemed to clear up my previous error, however I still get one error in `Pods>Pods>FacebookCore>SDKSettings.swift>enabledLoggingBehaviors` on line 151 `return Set(behaviors)`

The error is ([pic](https://imgur.com/a/Ml3VjRg)):

`Argument type 'SDKLoggingBehavior?' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'`

I'm not sure how to handle this error, does anyone know how to fix this to get the Facebook SDK working again?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside SDKSetting.swift

replace your  enabledLoggingBehaviors function with

```
public static var enabledLoggingBehaviors: Set<SDKLoggingBehavior> {
    get {
      let behaviors = FBSDKSettings.loggingBehavior().compactMap { object -> SDKLoggingBehavior? in
        if let value = object as? String {
          return SDKLoggingBehavior(sdkStringValue: value)
        }
        return nil
      }
      return Set(behaviors)
    }
    set {
      let behaviors = newValue.map({ $0.sdkStringValue })
      FBSDKSettings.setLoggingBehavior(Set(behaviors))
    }
  }
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this, solution worked perfectly. I'm pretty new so I'm not sure I'll completely understand, but what did this solution do that got it working? It looks like all that was changed was `flatMap` to `compactMap`. Thanks a lot for your help this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `flatMap` with `compactMap` that's it.